# Jquery Mobile / Ajax Page / Script not loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, load

As it is write on JQM documentation, it is possible to load page/form with ajax.

By example :

```
<form method="POST" action="mypage" data-ajax="true" id="myForm">

</form>
```

But when this form is post by, the JS script which is include in the response is not interpreted.

```
$("#myPage").live("pageinit", function() {
   // do something
});
```

This script is in JS file which is include in the head part of the page.

As it is describe on JQM [FAQ,](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/faq/scripts-and-styles-not-loading.html) there is a solution

> Another approach for page-specific scripting would be to include
>   scripts at the end of the body element when no data-role=page element
>   is defined, or inside the first data-role=page element. If you include
>   your custom scripting this way, be aware that these scripts will
>   execute when that page is loaded via AJAX or regular HTTP, so if these
>   scripts are the same on every page, you'll likely run into problems.
>   If you're including scripts this way, we'd recommend enclosing your
>   page content in a data-role="page" element, and placing scripts that
>   are referenced on every page outside of that element. Scripts that are
>   unique to that page can be placed in that element, to ensure that they
>   execute when the page is fetched via AJAX.

I've try to :

- include the JS file in my div (data-role="page")
- and include the JS script in my div (data-role="page")

But both doesn't work. The only solution I've found is to put data-ajax to false...

Any suggestion ? I would like to enable ajax navigation...

Answer (score 0):

Is the .live a valid method or you missed in loading third-party javascript library?

Better to use Chrome and turn on the Javascript Console and see the error.

$("#myPage").live("pageinit", function()